# pass default.yaml secret env's to deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets

I'm new to kubernetes.
I would like to know how to pass default.yaml in secrets to env in deployment?
i tried it separately but it saves the default empty and i want to override it
Thank you.

Comment: What is default.yaml

Comment: a file of all the default vars that i pass so the db can connect and persist (MongoDB)

Comment: you should add your manifest files for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the file in Secret or Configmap

Example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: nginx-data
data:
  default.yaml: |-
    server {
            server_name  _;
            listen 443 ssl http2;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
            ssl_certificate /etc/cert/tls.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/cert/tls.key;            
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
            }
        }
```

and inject it into the POD as per requirement. Update `default.yaml` as per need.

You can store and create the YAML inside the secret and inject into the deployment of **MongoD** it will work.

Configmap example : https://www.cloudytuts.com/guides/kubernetes/how-to-deploy-mongodb-on-kubernetes/

For more : https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/mounting-kubernetes-secret-single-file-inside-pod